# Некорректная выдача данных

Tags: c, указатели

Написан код на Си, при выводе на консоль поля структуры DataD выдается неверный результат вместо должного 365. Не могу понять в чем именно проблема.

```
struct DataT {
    int pereg; 
    struct DataD *first;
};
struct DataD {
    int day;
    struct DataD *next;
};
void randData(DataT [], int n);
DataD* randPereg(DataD *list,int pereg, int index);

void main(){
    struct DataT List[10];
    List[0].pereg = 2;
    randData(List,10);
    if(List[0].pereg>0) printf("day=%d\n", List[0].first->day);
    getch();
}
void randData(DataT myList [], int n){
    int i, pereg;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        pereg=myList[i].pereg;
        myList[i].first=randPereg(myList[i].first,pereg,i);
    }
}
DataD* randPereg(DataD *list,int pereg, int index){
    struct DataD curent;
    if(pereg>0) {
        list=&curent;
        list->day=365;
        list->next=randPereg(list->next,pereg-1, index);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Ну, а что вы хотите? Вы возвращаете из функции `randPereg` ссылку на локальную переменную, которая умрёт по выходу из функции. Разумеется, всё неправильно. Выделяйте память при помощи `malloc`.

Comment: Спасибо, за подсказку.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша функция `randPereg` полна ошибок:

```
DataD* randPereg(DataD * list,int pereg, int index)
{
    struct DataD curent;  // curent создается на стеке и удалится при выходе из функции 
    if(pereg > 0) 
    {
       list= &curent;    // присваивается адрес объекта на стеке curent
       list->day  = 365; // обращение к полям объекта curent
       list->next = randPereg(list->next, pereg-1, index);
    }
    return list; // возвращается адрес curent, который удалится 
                 // сразу после выхода из функции,
}
```

К тому времени, когда вы обратитесь по полученому из `randPereg` адресу, в блоке памяти на который он указывает будут уже другие данные.

Правильно создавать `curent` в куче с помощью `malloc`:

```
DataD * randPereg(DataD ** list,int pereg, int index)
{
    if(pereg > 0) 
    {
       *list= malloc(sizeof(DataD)); // создаем объект в куче
       (*list)->day  = 365;          // обращение к полям объекта
       (*list)->next = randPereg(&(*list)->next, pereg - 1, index);
    }
    return *list; // объект созданный в куче продолжает жить
                  // после выхода из функции
}
```

Обратите внимание, что теперь в `randPereg` надо передавать не просто указатель на `DataD`, а указатель на указатель на `DataD`. И второе, не забудьте удалять созданные объекты с помощью `free`.

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ, очень помог.

Comment: Если уж вы передаёте двойной указатель, имеет смысл возвращать из функции `void`.

Comment: @VladD какой в этом смысл?

Comment: @Cerbo: Ну, ТС использует возвращаемое значение как новое значение для первого параметра. Если первым параметром будет двойной указатель, то при этом нужное значение обновится само.